# Does Keccak have an eTCR mode?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, sha-3

On page 7 of [NIST's views on SHA-3's security requirements and Evaluation of attacks](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/hash/sha-3/Round1/Feb2009/documents/Nandi.pdf), I see that, at least at this point, NIST planned on offering SHA-3 having eTCR security (defined on page 3):

> **eTCR**: Find $M$ and then for a randomly chosen $r$, find $M’$
>   and $r’$ s.t. $H_r(M) = H_{r’}(M’), (r,M) ≠ (r’,M’)$ where
>   $H_r$ is the randomized hash.

However, I never saw any subsequent references to the eTCR property for the SHA-3 candidates.

Does SHA-3 have an eTCR mode?

Comment: This property is also known as "enhanced Target Collision Resistance".

Comment: Do you ask if there is a "standardized" randomized hashing mode of Keccak?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}\:$

Comment: Doesn't standard CR imply you get eTCR by simply concatenating the randomness and message and then applying the hash?

Comment: Yes. $\:$ Standard CR also implies you get eTCR by using zero bits of randomness $\hspace{1.5 in}$ and just applying the hash to the message. $\;\;$

Answer (score 1):

SHA-3 is conjectured to be collision-resistant, which is enough for $H(r \mathbin\| m)$ to be eTCR; if SHA-3 fell to a collision attack like MD5 and SHA-1 before it, it would nevertheless be surprising and remarkable and worthy of publication for SHA-3 to fall to a target collision attack as neither MD5 nor SHA-1 to my knowledge has, but one can only speculate about hypothetical developments past the failure of what is already only a conjecture.

The NIST-recommended ‘keyed hash’ function associated with SHA-3 is KMAC of [NIST SP 800-185](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-185/final), of course.  If you're still not comfortable with that, the NIST-recommended randomized hash for collision-resilient signatures is RMX of [NIST SP 800-106](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-106/final), which you could use with SHA-3 out of an abundance of paranoia, but I have never heard of anyone bothering to do that.